# MySQL Run SQL Script Error says "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2386: ordinal not in range(128)"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

***My setup:***

- late 2018 MacBook Air
- macOS Big Sur 11.5.2
- MySQL 8.0.26 Community Edition

I am trying to run an SQL file I downloaded by doing **`File > Run`** SQL Script.
But when I open that `.sql` file, I get an error message saying this:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2386: ordinal not in
> range(128)

If anyone could help me troubleshoot this, I would appreciate the help.
I am new to MySQL, so please be as specific as possible in your instructions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of this SQL query: `SELECT default_character_set_name, default_collation_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = '{database}';` Be sure to change `{database}` to the proper name of the database. If the collation of the DB (or target table) is wrong, then non-ASCII characters cannot be recorded.

Comment: This looks like a regression bug. Things were fine before 8.0x (we used to import .csv with lots of beyond-ASCII characters, accented, chinese, etc.) now this error is all over the place. Have not found a solution yet, but will post here if get lucky.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking at this error in the future:

I had the same errors trying to run sql script.

I have downloaded the most recent MySQL Workbench 6 and am able to run script without issue. Props to user cucu8 who mentions this above.

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Props to user cucu8 who mentions this above.

Comment: For me it was also working okay up to 8.0.21